# How effective is assertiveness training?

Tags: measurement, methodology

Has there been empirical research on the effectiveness  of assertiveness training?
What does it say about its effectiveness?

Comment: Hi Seno. Could you provide a little bit more context to the question? Is there a particular type of assertiveness training you want to learn about? How does such a training work in general? And why is the question relevant to you/science/CogSci.SE?